# filtering model on client angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have model like this:

```
{
    "TaskDate": "2015-01-04T00:00:00",
    "TimesheetList": [
        {
            "WorkItemId":24,
            "ProjectId":3,
            "ProjectName":"Hello world",
            "UserId":12,
            "UserName":"Anatoliy Svetliakov",
            "Date":"2015-01-04T22:00:00",
            "Task":"#34 : New task test",
            "TimeWorked":2,
            "Note":null,
            "InProgress":false
        }
    ]
}
```

This data shows in table with infinite-scroll. I need to create custom filter, that will filtering data by `Name` and/or `Data(from-to)`. Please give me an idea how to do this. I've created function but it doesn't work.

```
.filter('tsFilter', function() {
                return function(model, filter) {
                    var filtered = [];
                    if (model != null) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
                            filtered[i] = model[i];
                        }
                    }

                    if (filter != null) {
                        if (filter.UserId != null) {
                            for (i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                                for (var j = 0; j < filtered[i]['List'].length; j++) {
                                    if (filtered[i].List[j].UserId != filter.UserId) {
                                        filtered.splice(j, 1);
                                        j--;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for (i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                        if (filtered[i].List.length == 0) {
                            filtered.splice(i, 1);
                            i--;
                        }
                    }
                    return filtered;
                };
            })
```

On page table shows as:

```
<div class="timesheet-table-container">
    <table class="table-timesheet" id="table-body" infinite-scroll-immediate-check="false" infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-distance="1">
        <tbody ng-repeat="item in model | tsFilter: filter | limitTo: limits track by $index">
            <tr class="timesheet-day-block">
                <td colspan="6">
                    <span class="timesheet-date">{{item.TaskDate | dateFilter}}</span>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="timesheet-table-rows" ng-repeat="list in item.List" ng-form="logged">
                <td>{{list.ProjectName}}</td>
                <td>{{list.UserName}}</td>
                <td>{{list.Date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                <td>{{list.Task}}</td>
                <td>{{list.TimeWorked}}</td>
                <td>
                    <span style="width: 85%">{{list.Note}}</span>
                    <button class="active-delete-button" ng-click="removeTask(list)" style="display: inline-block; float:right">вњ–</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: not an answer.. but it would be better performancewise if you filter the data on server by passing filter parameters rather than doing it on client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - **demo:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/filtering-model-on-client-angularjs/

please refer to demo source code.

Comment: it's good but it works only for filter by UserId OR Date. I need to filtering by UserId OR Date and UserId AND Date

Comment: @HUSTLIN: i have updated it, sorry my bad.. try now and let me know.

Comment: Yea, it works, thanks!)
What is the service davilmaycode?

Comment: @HUSTLIN davilmaycode.it is my web design studio ;-) site is under construction due to lack of time =))) if you are insterested in some project just get in touch.